# Calculating bounds for a forecast using Autogluon's TabularPredictor

Tags: python, autogluon

I have a TabularPredictor for a regression problem.

Using TabularPredictor.predict, I can obtain a point forecast.

I would like to extract confidence bounds for the point forecast? How can I do that?

Under-the-hood, I understand that TabularPredictor is using decisions trees, so I believe it should be possible to get the forecasts from all the trees, and calculate a confidence interval from those.